# Unable to create a folder in root level 'My Drive' of Google drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, service-accounts, google-drive-picker

So I want to create a new folder in my Google drive. I am using a service account, Google drive api and if I was to create a folder in a parent folder it works. But at the root level it does not. Is it not possible?

```
import os
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '..............json'


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)


folder_name = 'OUTPUT'


folder_metadata = {
    'name': folder_name,
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
}
new_folder = drive_service.files().create(body=folder_metadata).execute()

# Print the folder ID of the newly created folder
print(f'Created folder: {new_folder["name"]} (ID: {new_folder["id"]})')
```